# Puzzling type mismatch after removing signature labels

Tags: ocaml

NB: this question actually has two important strands:

1. how to omit signature labels (e.g. `~f:`, `~init:`, etc.) from function calls;
2. how to debug complex type mismatches (in particular, how to extract actionable information from long composite type signatures in compiler error messages).

I hope the answer addresses both.

---

The following function compiles and performs as expected:

```
open Core.Std

let tally s =
  let upd m k =
    String.Map.change m k (function None -> Some 1 | Some n -> Some (n+1)) in
  let re = Str.regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" in
  let ws = List.map (Str.split re s) String.lowercase in

  List.fold_left ws ~init:String.Map.empty ~f:upd
```

OK, now: I want to get rid of the signature labels in the call to `List.fold_left` (last line).  My understanding was that I could do this as long as the arguments are given in the order shown in the function's documentation.

The signature for `List.fold_left` (as given in [this page](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Core_list)) is this:

```
val fold_left : 'a t -> init:'b -> f:('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

If I'm reading this correctly, the arguments in my call to `List.fold_left` are in the same order, but if I *just omit the signature labels* in the last line, so it becomes

```
  List.fold_left ws String.Map.empty upd
```

...the function no longer compiles, and the compiler's error message says:

```
File "tally.ml", line 1:
Error: The implementation tally.ml
       does not match the interface tally.cmi:
       Values do not match:
         val tally :
           bytes ->
           init:('a Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
                 (int Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
                  bytes -> int Core.Std.String.Map.t) ->
                 'b) ->
           f:(('a Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
               (int Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
                bytes -> int Core.Std.String.Map.t) ->
               'b) ->
              bytes ->
              'a Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
              (int Core.Std.String.Map.t ->
               bytes -> int Core.Std.String.Map.t) ->
              'b) ->
           'b
       is not included in
         val tally : bytes -> int Core.Std.String.Map.t
       File "tally.ml", line 3, characters 4-14: Actual declaration
```

My question has two parts:

1. what *else* (besides ordering the arguments appropriately) must I do to be able to omit the signature labels from the call to `List.fold_left`?;
2. is it possible to figure out what the solution (or at least narrow the problem further) from the error message)?

(I hope that with the answers to these two question I will be able to figure out why OCaml needs the labels here to determine that the function's type matches its interface.)

---

Based on Jeffrey Scofield's comment, I tried rewriting the function using the standard library's `List` module:

```
open Core.Std.String.Map
open Core.Std.String

let tally s =
  let upd m k =
    change m k (function None -> Some 1 | Some n -> Some (n+1)) in
  let re = Str.regexp "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" in
  let ws = List.map lowercase (Str.split re s) in

  List.fold_left upd ws empty
```

...but it still fails to compile:

```
File "tally.ml", line 10, characters 17-20:
Error: This expression has type int Map.t -> bytes -> int Map.t
       but an expression was expected of type ('a -> 'b) -> 'c -> 'a -> 'b
       Type
         int Map.t = (bytes, int, comparator_witness) Core_kernel.Core_map.t
       is not compatible with type 'a -> 'b
```

The signature of this `List.fold_left` has no labels (as Jeffrey Scofield pointed out), so adding them would make no sense.

I can't make any heads or tails of this error message, even though it's much shorter than the previous one.

NB: in order to use the standard library's `List.map` and `List.fold_left` I had to change the order of the arguments.

BTW: I am absolutely **outraged** to learn that `Core.Std.List.map` and `Core.Std.List.fold_left` (and who knows what else) have different signatures from the same-named functions in the standard library's `List` module.  If there is one sacrosanct rule for re-implementing a library is to respect its interface.  Violating this rule only sows confusion, and, as languages go, OCaml is already more confusing than it deserves to be.  Such sowing of confusion is *an unforgivable sin* in my book, and all by itself reason enough to shun `Core`, *no matter what other advantages it may provide*.  I'm now eager to weed it out from my OCaml work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703974/ocaml-using-list-fold-left-without-label

Comment: The OCaml standard library contains an unlabelled version of every list function. These are what I use, as I find labels to be more trouble than they're worth except in specific cases. I'm sure that others disagree.

Comment: @Marth: >ugh< that's *ugly*...  thanks

Comment: Simply, DO NOT try to omit labels.

Comment: You can just stop using OCaml Core if you're thinking that it is wrong.  There're two new excellent books, like "OCaml from the very beginning" and "More OCaml", that, I think is a better place to start, than RWO.

Comment: OCaml Core is not an extension for a standard library (for that we have `Batteries` and `Extlib`). It is a completely new library, that you can (and should) use without knowing OCaml's standard library at all.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml doesn't *need* labels to determine the type. Labels, were added for the convenience, so that one shouldn't remember the order of the arguments. So labels is just a keyword arguments. You shouldn't remove them, this was a decision of the library implementor, that you should use them. So you should either use labels, or choose another library. Indeed, `fold_left` without labels is much less readable, so removing them, would be a bad idea anyway.

As for the second question, then I think that it is very comprehensible. It states explicitly that your function has wrong type.

Labels aren't just augment type with extra information, it is a part of type declaration that creates a type different from the unlabeled.

Expression

```
let f x = x
```

has type

```
'a -> 'a
```

And expression

```
let g ~x = x
```

has a completely different type

```
x:'a -> 'a
```

You can't apply `g` without a labeled argument.

And, I don't want to say it, but otherwise you will find it yourelf... Notwithstanding, what I've said above, OCaml do allow you to omit labels in some cases. But the rules are subtle, and I consider it a bad practice. I do not think, that you should spend your time on learning the things, that are considered bad.

Comment: We have different ideas about what a "convenience" is.  In my book a convenience is nice to have, but not mandatory.  Since OCaml labels are sometimes mandatory, I would no longer consider them a mere "convenience".  Python too has support for labeled arguments, but there's *never* a situation in which one absolutely has to use them.  In this sense, Python's labeled arguments *are* a convenience; OCaml's, not so much, IMO.

Comment: @kjo OCaml's labels are a convenience in that you don't have to use them if you don't want them: they aren't needed for fundamental programming tasks and the standard library doesn't use them. If you choose to use them or to use a library that uses them, it's your choice. And by the way, you can't omit labels in all circumstances in Python either (approximatively speaking, you can with optional arguments but not when the function uses `**args`).

Comment: Spending most of the answer to explain that you cannot omit labels is misleading. You can sometimes omit labels, as you say in your last paragraph. Yes, the rules are subtle, but it does work in typical cases of a function call where you pass all the arguments. I don't understand the type that Ocaml infers here with the labels omitted in the call — a good answer to this question should explain that. (P.S. after reading the answer to the duplicate question, I do understand.)

Comment: @kjo, that because python is not an OCaml, and vice verse. They're very different languages with very different heritages. It is better to learn how to use language in a way how it was designed, instead of trying to "fix" the language or adapt it to your style. That's to my experience.

Comment: @Gilles, actually I never said that you can't. I've said, that you shouldn't. And I tried to empathize that adding label to a type definition will actually affect the type. Since I've got the feeling, that kjo actually missed it, and thought that labels aren't represented in a type world.

Comment: @Gilles: My understanding so far is that, in OCaml, if the *author* of the function *chooses* to use labels, then the *user* of the function is no longer entirely free to omit them.  In contrast, in Python, if the author defines a function with `def foo(x, y): ...`, the *user* of that function *may* (entirely as a convenience), use `foo(x=0, y=1)`, or `foo(y=1, x=0)`, but can also *always* use just `foo(0, 1)`.  This is what I was referring to, and is what I imagine one means when one says "labels/keywords are a *convenience* to obviate the need to remember the order of arguments."

Comment: @kjo even if the author of the function chooses to use labels, you still can omit the labels by following the orders of arguments. This is the same in Python. Anyway, if you want to / have to learn ocaml, forget about Python. Python is for the max conveniences and the tradeoff is you have write the similar amount of testing code as your normal code. OCaml is for max correctness, i.e., you need min amount of testing to ensure the correctness. After you master OCaml, you may feel Python is so ugly.